# Getting 500 error while running cURL Request with POST Data Using HTTP Controller.php

Tags: php, laravel, http, curl

This is my FlightController.php file

```
public function data(){

        // URL
        $apiURL = 'http://stageapi.ksofttechnology.com/API/FLIGHT/';

        // POST Data
        $postInput = [
            "TYPE"=> "AIR",
                "NAME"=> "GET_FLIGHT",
                "STR"=> [
                "AUTH_TOKEN"=> "***********************",
                "SESSION_ID"=> "",
                "TRIP"=> "1",
                "SECTOR"=> "D",
                "SRC"=> "DEL",
                "DES"=> "BOM",
                "DEP_DATE"=> "2022-12-10",
                "RET_DATE"=> "",
                "ADT"=> "1",
                "CHD"=> "0",
                "INF"=> "0",
                "PC"=> "",
                "PF"=> "",
                "HS"=> "D",
                ],
        ];

        // Headers
        $headers = [
          
        ];

        $response = Http::withHeaders($headers)->post($apiURL, $postInput);

        $statusCode = $response->status();
        $responseBody = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

        dd($responseBody); // body response
     
    }
```

Route File:

```
Route::post('/flightdata', [FlightController::class,'data']);
```

> Error: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Take a look at the server's error log or Laravel's laravel.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me, so it must be some small error, like maybe you didn't `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;` in your controller.

Make sure to set `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` file and clear your config cache with `php artisan config:clear` then you should be able to see the error message.